# How to read hyperlink into variable

Tags: linux, bash

I need to input into variable hyperlink and then download it via wget
Link is:
http://st-im.xyz.com/im/poster/2/1/0/xyz.com-Qwerty-2107544.jpg

But it seems like bash is not writing my link into variable. So, how can I fix this?

Code:

```
read $link
echo "Link is"
echo $link
wget "$link"
```

Output:

```
http://st-im.xyz.com/im/poster/2/1/0/xyz.com-Qwerty-2107544.jpg # This is my input
Link is

http://: Invalid host name.
```

Comment: `read link` not `read $link`

Comment: (...the "infinite loop" part of the dupe doesn't apply, but the immediate bug is the same).

Comment: thank you, I've made such silly mistake =)

Answer (score 0):

You are reading the value wrong.
It should be:

```
read link
```

$variable is for variable substitution. (Retrieving the value). Not for assigning the value.